# Web server complains "Multiple Choices" when using %3F instead of "?" in URL

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, firefox, browser

I use Lazarus-IDE (https://www.lazarus-ide.org/) for a project. One of the components allows one to type a URL for online help info, but such component does not accept "?" in the URL.

I thought that "%3F" is the correct encoding of "?" in a URL, so I used %3F in my setting, but somehow, web browsers, both Chrome and Firefox showed me a "Multiple Choices" error from the server, here is one example:

http://mcx.space/wiki/index.cgi%3FDoc/mcx_help#photon

when you click on it, it shows

```
Multiple Choices
The document name you requested (/wiki/index.cgi?Doc/mcx_help) could not be found on this server.
```

but if you copy/paste the decoded URL to the adderss, as

http://mcx.space/wiki/index.cgi?Doc/mcx_help#photon

then it displays the page correctly.

what was wrong? is %3F next to letter "D" had caused the problem? but even I replaced those to %3F%44, I still receive the same complain.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what was wrong?

You can not replace "?" (a delimiter character) with "%F3" (percent-encoding)

From [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2):

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI. **URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded octet are *not equivalent*.** Percent-encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded octet that corresponds to a reserved character, **will change how the URI is interpreted by most applications.**

Percent-encoding is intended to escape characters **used as data** that can be misunderstood by a server as special character. Not to replace a special character with alternative representation of itself.

You can't fool the aforementioned component this way.

Comment: thanks. I thought that was the reason, but could not find the right literature to confirm. thanks for the link.